# Best way to add authentication layer to static file requests?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, static-content

I am trying to figure out the best way to add an authentication check to requests for static assets on my server.

I am running Apache2.4 and PHP/Laravel, which runs by serving static content directly from the `DocumentRoot` and enters at the `index.php` to handle the dynamic routes.

I have been searching and found a couple options, but I'm not sure what consensus would be on best practices and most efficient:

---

1) Create and set an ActionHandler in Apache to call a CGI script to serve static content. This script would open a DB connection for each request, check access control rights, and return a 301 or serve the content. My thought on this is that performance will take a huge hit because of opening a new DB connection for each request.

I tried to add:

```
Action serve-static /var/www/file-server.py
AddHandler serve-static .js .css
```

to the `<Directory>` block, but that caused all css/js to return 404.

---

2) User a combo of `mod_rewrite` and `mod_proxy` to proxy all requests for static files to another application server (or load balance to multiple) which would have an open DB connection already, perform an authentication check and serve the file back appropriately. My concern with this approach is that I think Apache could become a bottleneck on the downlink back to the client?

I start with a `<Directory /var/www/html/app/public>` block that contains the whole application

I'm not very familiar with `mod_rewrite` and `mod_proxy`, so I think I could create something like

```
<Directory /var/www/html/app/public/static>
    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteRule    "(.*)$"  "http://fileserver/$1"  [P]
    ProxyPassReverse "/public/static" "http://fileserver/"
</Directory>
```

But I cannot get this to proxy requests to the fileserver layer to even test efficiency.

---

Any insight here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the static content is already on the web server, start simple. Skip (for now) the CGI script, proxy, URL rewriting, and caching.

In a Directory directive for static, use [httpd's auth modules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html) to lock that down.  You imply a DB connection, which means mod_authn_dbd and mod_authz_dbm, and require your database to have password hashes supported by the modules.

You will want caching eventually, multiple DB queries per document does not perform well. An Apache implementation is [mod_authn_socache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_socache.html), and it can stuff auths into its shared object cache, which can be backed by shared memory, memcached, and more.

You could do similar caching in the framework of your web app. That's an exercise for the reader, as it is more development than configuring a web server.